# How to find rows where all values of a column are same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `user_test_access` which stores `test_id` and `user_id`.

`user_test_access` table stores all the uses who have access to the test as well as which user created the test.

| id | test_creator | test_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 901 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 903 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 904 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 905 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 | 906 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 907 |
| 7 | 0 | 3 | 908 |

I want a query to return all the `test_id` where there is no creator. i.e test_creator = 0.

Desired Result:

For the particular data set the answer would be `test_id` 1 and 2.
The reason test_id 3 is not included is because `user_id` 907 is the `test_creator` for it.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT test_id from user_test_access WHERE id = ALL(SELECT id from user_test_access WHERE test_creator=0)
```

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a missing testcreator is encoded by the value `0`, you can just group by the `test_id` and select only ids where the sum is zero

```
select test_id 
from user_test_table
group by test_id
having sum(test_creator) = 0
```

Comment: Since I want all the test_id without any test_creator. Shouldn't we be using `having sum(test_creator) = 0` instead?

Comment: @GauravKhe You are absolutely right. Thx ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use not exists operator as the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT test_id
FROM user_test_access T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_test_access D
  WHERE D.test_id=T.test_id AND D.test_creator=1)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HdN0Nk1h).